# Why is This Not Showing Anything?

Tags: electron

main:

```
const { BrowserView, app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    // In the main process.
    const { BrowserView, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

    const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

    const view = new BrowserView()
    win.setBrowserView(view)
    view.setBounds({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300 })
    view.webContents.loadURL('https://electronjs.org')
})
```

versions:
npm: '7.24.0',
node: '16.10.0',

start command:
npm start

This is just showing a blank page. I have spent 3+ hours debugging my original program, so I copied this from the docs and ran it, but it's still not working. Any idea why this is happening?

Edit: I found a similar issue on GitHub and I believe it's an issue with the recent version of Electron. I'll take any suggestions but I think I'll just have to wait for this to be fixed for now.

Comment: npm install electron?

Comment: I'd check the DevTools/Console for any error messages...

Comment: Yeah, Electron is installed properly and everything. The window opens and I get the menu bar at the top, but the page is blank. I noticed it actually does load occasionally and I think I've found an issue for it on the GitHub, and I believe it's a bug. Hopefully it's fixed soon. 

As for the console this is the only error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I think you must load a file on the browser window like `win.loadFile('blank.html')`

Comment: As seen above I'm loading a URL, do you think that doing a file instead will make a difference? Or do you mean to load the blank file followed by the URL? I don't understand why I'd have to do that though, seeing as that isn't required for a browser window and browser views are supposed to work the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed it, it's an issue with version 14.0.0. If you're having this same issue just rollback to version 13.4.0 with

npm install electron@13.4.0

and hope they fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Question: What does your package.json look like?

Your package.json file determines what happens when you run commands such as `npm run start` or `npm run dev`

For example (please observe context, this is not a "one size fits all"), in my package.json I have this:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron ./app/",
},
```

Mine may be a bit more "advanced" then some, a basic example would be to just do something like this:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "electron .",
},
```

The electron documentation goes over this in a bit more detail: [Quick Start | Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start)

Once you understand the concept, you may consider using a "boilerplate" type solution to properly start projects, this is just handy in general.  I would not suggest doing this until you actually understand how a project should be setup because knowledge is magical.

One such solution I utilize and recommend: [ElectronForge](https://www.electronforge.io)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'll be a bit busy today and tomorrow so I'll get to them later.